# how can I make my database tables be automatically updated when the system date and time reaches a due date?

Tags: database

I am writing a **web application**. In its **database** there is a **table** that keeps some due dates. **Another table** has two columns: `name` and `state`. I want the `state` column to be automatically updated when any of those due dates arrives (the updated value is calculated according to some logic in my program).

How can I implement this functionality? Is it common to run another program (independent of my web application) on the server machine to check the database for due dates and update the table or there are other ways?

Comment: @X.Jacobs "Its" (meaning belonging to "it") has no apostrophe. I already edited the question to correct that mistake, then you put it back. Learn how to spell and leave "its" there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although some databases support scheduled tasks, most DBAs use `cron` to schedule a task that does the work.

I suggest you do the same.

(Thanks to catcall for his comment)

Comment: Depends on the dbms. Some have task schedulers--PostgreSQL, DB2. Probably others.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT 'DBNAME'.'EVENTNAME'

ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY

ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE

DO
    BEGIN
     /*sql statements*/
     UPDATE tableName SET state = 'newState' where NOW() = (SELECT * FROM tableWithDates);
    END

DELIMITER ;
```

---

this is a code that creates an event in MySql. you can update data in your tables using Mysql events. this event runs every 1 day and then executes the sql query. MySql events runs also on the background.